# ¿Cómo puedo recoger los datos de un formulario en la misma página, sin que aparezca error "UNDEFINED INDEX:?

Tags: php

Tengo un problema con *PHP*, estoy aprendiéndolo ahora, de hecho, he empezado hace nada y no se mucho sobre este lenguaje, de hecho, es posible que sea un error sencillo de resolver para alguien experimentado, pero llevo días con ello y no lo consigo.

He creado un formulario básico donde introducir dos datos, para que se muestren en la misma página, hasta ahí bien, incluso funciona el código. Mi problema es que al abrir la página me aparece un error de *PHP*:

> "Undefined Index:"

¿Cómo puedo hacer que ese error no aparezca?

> **PD:** No se como se hace para que aparezca el código como si estuviera en un procesador de texto como sublime, es mi primera pregunta.

El código que he hecho es el siguiente:

```
    <form action="funcion_parametro.php" method="post">
        Introduzca su nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre"> <br>
         Introduzca su nota (0-10): <input type="number" name="numero"> <br>
         <input type="submit" name="Enviar" value="Enviar"> <br><br>

function notaexamen($var1 = ' ')<br>
{<br>
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];<br>
    $nota = $_POST['nota'];
    

if ($nota >= "5") <br>
{<br>
    echo "Felicidades " . $nombre . " Tiene un " . $nota;<br>
    echo " en el examen." . " Ha ";
    echo $var1;

else{

    echo "Señor/a " . $nombre . " Tiene un " . $nota . ", ha suspendido, vuelva a presentarse al exámen.";
}

}

notaexamen('aprobado.');
```

Answer (score 0):

Amigo por lo que veo necesitas cerrar la etiqueta de `</form>`, segunda cosa, sugiero usar tambien el atributo id="nombre".

Answer (score 0):

Hay 3 errores críticos
El primero en el formulario:

```
<input type="number" name="numero">
```

debe ser

```
<input type="number" name="nota">
```

El segundo, en la función, el `if` no tiene llaves de cierre. Acostumbrate a [indentar el código](https://www.google.com/search?q=indentacion) para hacer un código bonito, legible y facil de localizar esos errores.

El tercero es que no puedes poner html suelto dentro de PHP. Hay unas etiquetas `<br>` dentro de la función de PHP, los cuales no entiende y terminan dando error. Si quieres imprimir html: O rompes el PHP o lo imprimes con `echo`

Con esos errores saneados, el código finalmente debe quedar así:

HTML

```
<form action="funcion_parametro.php" method="POST">
    Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre">
    Nota: <input type="text" name="nota">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

PHP (*funcion_parametro.php*)

```
function notaexamen($var1 = ' ') {   
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $nota = $_POST['nota'];
    echo '<br />';
    if ($nota >= "5") {
        echo "Felicidades " . $nombre . " Tiene un " . $nota;
        echo " en el examen." . " Ha ";
        echo $var1;
    } else {
        echo "Señor/a " . $nombre . " Tiene un " . $nota . ", ha suspendido, vuelva a presentarse al exámen.";
    }
}
notaexamen('aprobado.');
```

Comment: Considero que esos 3 echo en el segmento del if se pueden quedar en 1 solo y con eso facilitar la lectura para que de paso al OP le sea mas simple